# Binding Gridview With Different Names Regardless of Property names

Tags: asp.net

```
                public class Emp
                {
                    public int ID { get; set; }
                    public string  Name { get; set; }
                }

                    List<Emp> lstEmp=new List<Emp>();
                    lstEmp.Add(new Emp{ID=1,Name="ABC"});
                    gridview1.DataSource=lstEmp;
                    gridview1.DataBind();
```

This will show PropertyNames as Column Names when binded to a gridview But Can I Bind Gridview with Emp Object & different Column Names I mean Column names should not be ID & Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean Columns' Headers

Yes you can, In your `gridview1` data bound event write this:

```
protected void gridview1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee No.";
    gridview1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Employee Name";
}
```

Change headers accordingly, Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My gridview Id is GridviewResult

```
         GridViewResults.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Employee no";
        GridViewResults.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Employee Name";
        GridViewResults.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "Registration Date";
```